# error running hadoop mapreduce to run jar files

Tags: hadoop

i have tried to run the zip files download from the link https://github.com/verma7/GeneticAlgorithmsUsingMapReduce
But i cant run it in Apache Hadoop.
which file i should run from the zip  to perform Mapreduce task?
 Can anyone please tell me how to work with Hadoop  using the zip files from the following link
https://github.com/verma7/GeneticAlgorithmsUsingMapReduce
    I'm facing several problems while doing this 
please help me out.
I want to know the step by step procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the README file in link? It has step by step instructions on how to run the MR job.

```
    Requirement: Hadoop 0.19 or higher (and it's dependencies)

###################################################################################
You may need to modify the variable "rootDir" in MapReduce.java and CGA.java to
point to your home directory or some directory on the HDFS that you have read 
and write permissions on.

To compile the class files and the jar files, run

$ ant compile jar

This will create a build and bin directory for the class files, by compiling 
against Hadoop 0.19 jar located in the lib directory. Also, it will create 
ga.jar which MapReduces simple genetic algorithm and cga.jar which 
MapReduces compact genetic algorithm.

###################################################################################
To execute, go to the root Hadoop directory and run, 

$ hadoop jar ga.jar <nMaps> <nReducers> <variables> <nIterations> <popTimesNlogN>

where <nMaps> and <nReducers> is the number of mappers and reducers you want to 
start, <variables> is the size of the ONEMAX problem that this program solves, 
<nIterations> is the number of iterations you want to run and <popTimesNlogN> sets
the size of the population to a multiple of n log n, where n is the number of 
variables.

For example, 
$ hadoop jar ga.jar 4 4 10000 100 10
```